# Why is my jQM datepicker not running $.datepicker({onSelect:function(){}}) properly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker

Basically whenever a date is picked, nothing is run. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/pwLMr/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#date1").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            alert("HAHA");
        }
    });
});
```

The alert above doesn't run.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/rYaRy/)</kbd>

Change

```
<input id="date1" data-role="date" type="text">
```

to

```
<input id="date1" type="text">
```

---

Remove `data-role="date"` as it for jQuery Mobile to create a datepicker .

Comment: If we do that, the datepicker doesn't style properly and has no <- and -> buttons to change months.

Comment: @Geoyws Missing jQuery UI css file i suspect . See --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/rYaRy/1/